# Test with Espresso randomly crashed on IllegalStateException: Already interrogating

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am using testing with [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) + [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista)

Versions:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.adevinta.android:barista:4.2.0'
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already interrogating!
at androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.checkSanity(Interrogator.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadUntilIdle(UiControllerImpl.java:17)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:3)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:14)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(UiControllerImpl.java:8)
at com.adevinta.android.barista.internal.viewaction.SleepViewAction$1.perform(SleepViewAction.java:27)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:22)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

This Exception appears randomly across all versions of Android from 6 to 11. How to debug this?